# Using the Spotify API with Sencha

Tags: extjs, spotify

I've read through the Spotify API docs and it describes how to set everything up using Node.js. I have 0 knowledge of Node.js and have been using EXTjs or plain javascript.

Has anyone ever used the Spotify API with a Sencha app? If so, how did you set up your proxy to make calls?

Comment: Sencha's own engineer, [Lee Boonstra, has done so](https://www.sencha.com/blog/how-to-build-a-great-looking-universal-app-with-ext-js-part-1/), the app can be seen in action [here](http://ladysign-apps.com/spotifinder/). You should be able to retrieve and reverse engineer the source code from there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out.

Comment: This should be the actual answer to this question :-)